# CSS background-image not showing, but does when I apply style to the element in dev tools?

Tags: css, background-image, webpack

I am using Webpack to load an image to use as a background image. When I apply it using CSS, the div takes on any property I give it other than a background image..

```
.cover {
  background-image: url(../assets/images/childcarer_background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  min-height:500px;
}

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cover">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="homepage.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I inspect this in Chrome dev tools, the image is being loaded (I can access it directly) and if I copy the style from the .cover and apply it to element.style within Developer Tools, the style is applied as expected..

It will even overwrite the style when I apply it directly to the element...

[image]

This works, but obviously isn't sustainable.

If I inline the style, it works..

```
<div class="row" style="background-image:url(2769a294377fdc1af5fa011c9bedc6a0.jpg);">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

but if I try to make the stylesheet background `!important`...

[image]

It overwrites the background image with a blank background!

Why is this happening?

Comment: Inline CSS has another path to the image than an external CSS file. Did you take that into account?

Comment: @JoostS I believe Webpack handles that for me..? The image is accessible on localhost:3000/image.jpg, and the page is at /home.html, so they're in the same directory

Comment: Does this work: `background:url(2769a294377fdc1af5fa011c9bedc6a0.jpg)!important;`?

Comment: @JoostS I have updated the OP

Comment: Did you try using background instead of background-image?

Comment: Any chance you can get this reproduced in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yep! Same result, something is there, but that something is nothing..  I'm not sure I can reproduce the same conditions in jsfiddle involving webpack? Apologies, I'm not too familiar with those tools

Comment: @JoostS hints at but isn't explicit — the path `url(../assets/images/...etc...)` is relative to **the CSS file**, _**NOT**_ the page URL, but when you paste it into the dev tools then it _**IS**_ relative to the page.  This fact is the most common cause that I have seen for all kinds of "my image is not showing" problems.

Comment: @StephenP Ignore the path in the CSS file. I am using Webpack. It is bundled into homepage.js and the image is accessible at /2769a294377fdc1af5fa011c9bedc6a0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **!important** to your background element. So...

```
.cover {
  background-image: url(../assets/images/childcarer_background.jpg) !important;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height:500px;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, but as before, if I add it directly to the element, it works! This is strange.

Comment: Avoid adding `!important` just to fix mysteriously "not working" things — [abuse of !important is rampant](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) and is generally a crutch, when one _should_ fix the specificity of the rules you're trying to override.  Even though it can be used by web authors,`!important` was meant more for _end users_ ["This CSS feature improves accessibility of documents by giving users with special requirements control over presentation."](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)

Answer (score 0):

try but eliminating space between the colon and url. no space should solve it.

```css
.cover {
  background-image:url(../assets/images/childcarer_background.jpg) !important;
```